# Swift - Why can't self be used in a closure before all stored properties are initialized?

Tags: swift, oop, closures, self

I am trying to make an `Actor` class as well as a `Movie` class that can be decoded from a JSON file. There is also a dictionary, `allActors`, containing each `Actor` instance so that each movie that is decoded references the same `Actor` instance. Also, when the `Actor` is added to the `Movie`'s `cast` array, the `Movie` is appended to the `Actor`'s `filmography` array. Here is the code I have so far:

```swift
public var allActors = [String: Actor]()

public final class Actor {
    public let name: String
    public var filmography: [Movie]

    public init(name: String, filmography: [Movie] = Array()) {
        self.name = name
        self.filmography = filmography
    }
}

public final class Movie: Codable {
    public let title: String
    public var cast: [Actor]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case cast
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        cast = Array() // fourth line of this initializer
        cast = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: .cast).map {
            let actor: Actor
            if let recurringActor = allActors[$0] {
                actor = recurringActor
            } else {
                let newActor = Actor(name: $0)
                allActors[$0] = newActor
                actor = newActor
            }
            actor.filmography.append(self)
            return actor
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(cast.map {$0.name}, forKey: .cast)
    }
}
```

This code works, however, at the fourth line of the `Movie`'s `init(from:)` initializer, `cast` is set to an empty array. This seems redundant, but if I remove it, I get the following error:

> 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

Is there a way I can avoid this error? I'm not using any properties of `self`, so I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to use the `Movie`'s reference in a closure.

Comment: where is allActors declared? Can you post your JSON string?

Comment: You can simply initialize your `cast` with an empty array. `var cast: [Actor] = []`

Comment: @LeoDabus allActors is declared at the top of the code fence. The JSON file is here: https://pastebin.com/XjGD5q2g

Answer (score 2):

You can’t say

```
actor.filmography.append(self)
```

until `self` is fully initialized. That doesn’t happen until its `cast` property has a value. (And all its other properties too of course.) That fully explains the phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but you can simply decode your movies, reduce it into a dictionary and map its key/value pairs into your actors array:

```
struct Movie: Codable {
    let title: String
    let cast: [String]
}
```

---

```
struct Actor: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let filmography: [String]
    var description: String { "Name: \(name) - Movies: \(filmography)" }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let movies = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Movie].self, from: Data(json.utf8))

let actors = movies.reduce(into: [:]) { dict, movie in
    for name in movie.cast {
        dict[name, default: []].append(movie.title)
    }
}.map(Actor.init)

print(actors)
```

---

This will print:

> [Name: Kevin Bacon - Movies: ["Diner", "Footloose", "Flatliners"],
>   Name: Mark Ruffalo - Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: John Laughlin -
>   Movies: ["Footloose"], Name: Beth Grant - Movies: ["Flatliners"],
>   Name: Liev Schreiber - Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: John Slattery -
>   Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Paul Guilfoyle - Movies: ["Spotlight"],
>   Name: Len Cariou - Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Neal Huff - Movies:
>   ["Spotlight"], Name: Colette Blonigan - Movies: ["Diner"], Name:
>   Frances Lee McCain - Movies: ["Footloose"], Name: Dianne Wiest -
>   Movies: ["Footloose"], Name: Ellen Barkin - Movies: ["Diner"], Name:
>   Michael Tucker - Movies: ["Diner"], Name: Rachel McAdams - Movies:
>   ["Spotlight"], Name: Joshua Rudoy - Movies: ["Flatliners"], Name:
>   Jamey Sheridan - Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Patricia Belcher -
>   Movies: ["Flatliners"], Name: Stanley Tucci - Movies: ["Spotlight"],
>   Name: Hope Davis - Movies: ["Flatliners"], Name: Maureen Keiller -
>   Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Tim Daly - Movies: ["Diner"], Name: Billy
>   Crudup - Movies: ["Eat Pray Love", "Spotlight"], Name: Steve
>   Guttenberg - Movies: ["Diner"], Name: Hadi Subiyanto - Movies: ["Eat
>   Pray Love"], Name: Mike O 'Malley - Movies: ["Eat Pray Love"], Name:
>   Brian d'Arcy James - Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Gene Amoroso -
>   Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Rushita Singh - Movies: ["Eat Pray
>   Love"], Name: Julia Roberts - Movies: ["Flatliners", "Eat Pray Love"],
>   Name: Kiefer Sutherland - Movies: ["Flatliners"], Name: Clement Fowler
>   - Movies: ["Diner"], Name: Michael Cyril Creighton - Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Kimberly Scott - Movies: ["Flatliners"], Name:
>   Viola Davis - Movies: ["Eat Pray Love"], Name: Sophie Thompson -
>   Movies: ["Eat Pray Love"], Name: Javier Bardem - Movies: ["Eat Pray
>   Love"], Name: Tuva Novotny - Movies: ["Eat Pray Love"], Name: John
>   Lithgow - Movies: ["Footloose"], Name: Laurie Heineman - Movies:
>   ["Spotlight"], Name: Tim Progosh - Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Arlene
>   Tur - Movies: ["Eat Pray Love"], Name: Lynne Marta - Movies:
>   ["Footloose"], Name: Jim Youngs - Movies: ["Footloose"], Name: Daniel
>   Stern - Movies: ["Diner"], Name: James Franco - Movies: ["Eat Pray
>   Love"], Name: Gita Reddy - Movies: ["Eat Pray Love"], Name: Jessica
>   James - Movies: ["Diner"], Name: Kelle Kipp - Movies: ["Diner"], Name:
>   Christine Hakim - Movies: ["Eat Pray Love"], Name: Douglas Dirkson -
>   Movies: ["Footloose"], Name: Kathryn Dowling - Movies: ["Diner"],
>   Name: William Baldwin - Movies: ["Flatliners"], Name: Benjamin Mouton
>   - Movies: ["Flatliners"], Name: Sarah Jessica Parker - Movies: ["Footloose"], Name: Lori Singer - Movies: ["Footloose"], Name: Paul
>   Reiser - Movies: ["Diner"], Name: Chris Penn - Movies: ["Footloose"],
>   Name: Oliver Platt - Movies: ["Flatliners"], Name: Michael Keaton -
>   Movies: ["Spotlight"], Name: Mickey Rourke - Movies: ["Diner"], Name:
>   Claudia Cron - Movies: ["Diner"], Name: Richard Jenkins - Movies:
>   ["Eat Pray Love", "Spotlight"], Name: Luca Argentero - Movies: ["Eat
>   Pray Love"]]